# Connect Bot to Skype and Teams

Tags: azure, bots, skype, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm currently trying to figure out Azure and the `Web App Bot` Resource.

I've learned that it is possible to create a `Web App Bot` and connect it to channels like `Skype` or `Teams` for example. Though as far as I can tell if the bot is connected to both `Skype` and `Teams` the bot in `Skype` has no information about what the bot in `Teams` is doing and vice versa.

So I wondered if it is possible to link them up somehow.

Would it be possible to write a message `My Text` to the bot in `Skype` and the bot in `Teams` then writes this message `My Text` into a `Teams channel`?

Comment: Please have a look at [Proactive messaging for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive) documentation to know how you can send message to Microsoft Teams chat if you have user information.

Comment: Just an FYI that the Skype for Business channel is going to be deprecated at the end of June this year for new bots and existing bots will stop working in Skype for Business at the end of October this year (2019) as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness?view=azure-bot-service-4.0. I’m not sure what is happening with the consumer version of Skype @Wajeed-MSFT might be able to shed some light on this.

Comment: Yes, Skype for Business channel in Bot Framework is being deprecated. Bot with multiple channels hits the same endpoint, in the payload you receive channel name like msteams. As there is a common code base, you can easily communicate across channels using Proactive Messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I suggest reading over some of the tutorials and documentation on the Bot Framework? It might help to have a clear idea of the related concepts, such as:

- **Web App Bot**: A Web app bot is used to create a new full-fledged bot service that can be modified, build and deployed online.
- **Azure Bot Service**: Azure Bot Service enables you to host intelligent, enterprise-grade bots with complete ownership and control of your data. The Microsoft Azure Bot Service helps you manage, connect, and deploy your bot across devices and popular channels. Azure Bot Service and Bot Framework provide tools to build, test, deploy, and manage intelligent bots all in one place.
- **Channel**: A [channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) is a connection between the bot and communication apps. The Bot Framework Service, configured through the Azure portal, connects your bot to these channels and facilitates communication between your bot and the user.
- **Bot Channels Registration**: A Bot Channels Registration bot service allows you to use Bot Service functionality. A registration bot lets you connect your bot to channels.

In order to have a bot that works with Skype or Teams, you need to have a [bot channels registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). If you already have a bot hosted elsewhere and you would like to use the Bot Service to connect it to channels such as Skype, Twilio, Messenger etc., you will need to register your bot with the Bot Service.

Coming back to your question, you can create a Web App Bot and connect it to Skype or Teams, but neither Teams nor Skype has any information about the bot's conversation with the other channel as its channel-specific. So the bot can interact and communicate with Skype and Teams channels separately but they cannot be linked.

If the user saves the entirety of conversations in some sort of transcript storage, that could be tapped by both, then it might be possible, but not at the same time, and it would take a decent amount of code to implement.

Hope this helps!!